Why did Aquinas think an erroneous conscience binds?
Quodlibet III, q. 12 a. 2 co.:

it must be said that every conscience, whether right or erroneous, whether in things evil in themselves or in things indifferent, is obligatory, such that he who acts against conscience sins.
Latin:Et ideo dicendum est quod omnis conscientia, sive recta, sive erronea, sive in per se malis, sive in indifferentibus, est obligatoria; ita quod qui contra conscientiam facit, peccat.
Davies, O.P. & Nevitt transl.:conscience is always binding, whether it is mistaken or not, and whether it is a question of things evil in themselves or morally neutral. Therefore, it is a sin to act against one’s conscience.


binds but does not excuse is the Thomistic view.

@eques It excuses if it's invincible ignorance.

@Geremia Aquinas uses the term "invincible ignorance" in the Quodlibetal, but not in the Summa. In the Summa (https://www.newadvent.org/summa/2019.htm#article5), his definition is a little broader.

What you quote is the conclusion of St. Thomas's explanation. His full answer to the question of whether a mistaken conscience binds under pain of sin is:
Quodlibet III, q. 12 a. 2 co. (Davies, O.P. & Nevitt transl.):

Answer: Although an act gets its nature from its object, its nature does not come from its object’s matter, but from its object’s formal aspect. Seeing a stone, for instance, does not get its nature from the stone as a stone, but as something colored, which is the essential object of sight. Now, every human act has the nature of guilt or merit insofar as it is willed, and the object of the will—its proper formal aspect—is an apprehended good. Hence, a human act is judged virtuous or vicious because of the apprehended good at which the will essentially aims, not because of the act’s material object. If a man kills his servant, for instance, but believes that he is killing his father, then he is guilty of the sin of patricide. But if a hunter has done his due diligence, and thinks he is killing a deer, but accidentally kills his father, then he is innocent of the crime of patricide.
So, take something that is not itself against God’s law, such as picking up a stick off the ground or taking an oath. Now, suppose that a person’s conscience mistakenly apprehends it as being against God’s law, and the person’s will then aims at it accordingly. Such a person’s will is clearly aimed at something against God’s law, essentially and formally speaking, even though its matter is not against God’s law, and in fact may even be in accord with God’s law. Hence, such a person clearly shows contempt for God’s law, and necessarily sins as a result.
Accordingly, conscience is always binding, whether it is mistaken or not, and whether it is a question of things evil in themselves or morally neutral. Therefore, it is a sin to act against one’s conscience.

The great 20th century moral theologian Dominic M. Prümmer, O.P., writes (Handbook of Moral Theology p. 60):


SECOND PRINCIPLE. Everyone is obliged to follow his conscience whether it commands or forbids some action, not only when it is true but also when it is in invincible error*.There is a reason for the use of the two words “commands” and “forbids,” for if conscience permits or merely counsels some line of action there is no strict obligation to follow it. It is patently obvious why we must obey a true conscience, and the reason for man’s obligation to follow an invincibly erroneous conscience is that failure to do so would mean that he was acting contrary to the subjective norm of morality and was therefore committing sin. Thus, for example, a person who is convinced that he ought to tell a lie in order to save his friend from some danger is bound to tell the lie; in so doing he does not commit formal sin. Anyone who thinks that to-day is a fast-day, although as a matter of fact it is not, and in spite of his conviction does not observe the fast commits formal sin.


*Also called invincible (or inculpable) ignorance; cf. vincible (or culpable) ignorance.

Well, Aquinas is definitely more a catholic side of things.
Based on the vatican website They seem to start from a perspective of "you know if you're doing something wrong" so if you intentionally do something wrong, it is your fault.
An erroneous conscience however seems to be one that is "ignorant" of something. If nothing else, most times "ignorance of the law" is not a valid excuse for breaking a law in a country. But this isn't your question, you want to know why an incorrect conscience if you acted against it, would be a sin.

I don't have a direct answer, but I do have an answer about this concept and perhaps Aquinas used a similar logic or reasoning.
Fundamentally your "inner moral code" is the voice of your conscience. It is not perfect, but it is your "code of conduct" that it is trying to enforce. So if you act against your own inner structure of value, you have pushed your inner system of values into a more "evil" form.
For example, we all know that parking in handicap reserved spaces is wrong. But people do it. They probably didn't start by parking in those spaces, they probably got frustrated one day after circling around for 20 minutes and did it despite their conscience. And they didn't get punished. So the next time they only circled 10 minutes... and then 2min... and then immediately after not finding a parking spot... and at some point they don't look for another spot.
This is what happens to your conscience, if you act against it. Your conscience will "bend" to fit your actions more and more.

“If you lie, to yourself or to other people, then you corrupt the structure that you use to interact with Being. You corrupt it. And if you corrupt it, then if you listen to it, it will guide you to the wrong way”. -Jordan Peterson, Lecture on the Necessity of Virtue.

So I cannot speak for Aquinas, but I would say likely makes the same point as Peterson did above. If you corrupt your conscience/intuition by acting against it, you weaken it. Actions are how you train your internal processes. Your conscience is a "tool" in your mind that helps you to avoid sin/mistakes. Intentionally damaging this tool is a sinful action.
It is easier to think about it with "lies". Every time we lie, we are adding some untruth to an internal cycle that guides us. This internal cycle is what we rely on for determining what is true or false. If you weaken it to the point that you cannot rely on it, then you start to rely on other things (ideologies, cults, idols, etc). And all those things are replacing your ability to properly think, believe, reason, etc. and that eventually replaces God in your life. Acting against your conscience is just lie to yourself in the form of an action. because you are telling yourself that "it's okay" when you really know it is not.
So there are multiple ways that acting against your "pure" or "deeply flawed" conscience will result in worse outcomes and more sin.

The question is literally why did Aquinas teach conscience binds, not why anyone else does so. The rest of this is at best theological speculation which does not align with what Aquinas means. For example, Aquinas wouldn't say the inner moral code is the "voice of the conscience". Conscience is a judgment of reason, not a power in Aquinas. Some of your points are close.

@eques "I don't have a direct answer, but I do have an answer about this concept and perhaps Aquinas used a similar logic or reasoning." I mean, I admitted as much. And I look forward to someone else providing a dramatically more accurate answer.

Admitting as much is half-credit at best. You should answer the question which is asked.

@eques I look forward to your deeply insightful answer into the thoughts of someone who has fallen asleep in Christ. Perhaps you are more familiar with Aquinas and have better sources then I do.

Fallen asleep in Christ? Why is that relevant here?

@eques It was a polite way saying "I look forward to your answer on the internal intentions and thoughts of someone who has been dead for centuries"

I don't have to provide thoughts on the internal intentions. Aquinas wrote 50-60 folio sized volumes.
